# Tools for development SOAP-service on Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby, soap

Which set of libraries and tools would you recommend to use for development SOAP-service on Ruby 1.9 - soap-tools, web-servers, or maybe a web-framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://aws.rubyonrails.org/, when it's explained how to **create** web services within RubyOnRails.

Comment: Of course, it's not so uptodate mainly because SOAP support - in Rails - was replaced in favor of REST months ago (if not years...)

Comment: Its posible to use Action Web Service with Rails 3 or any other (not Rails 2) web-framework?

Answer (score 2):

I have researched this myself. As far as I can tell, there is just one current implementation:
[wash_out](https://github.com/roundlake/wash_out)

It is a very nice to do SOAP in Rails. It does the most basic stuff but it isn't a complete SOAP implementation. I think you are in for a world of hurt if you are building a SOAP service on Rails.

Soap Ui is a pretty good way to test/debug/etc.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

SOAP doesn't seem to be popular in Ruby land. The only library for creating services I know of is SOAP4R (which comes bundled with Ruby), and the documentation for it isn't very detailed.

Comment: Yea, you are right. But SOAP4R doesn't support ruby 1.9 now and forks are not tested well